# celery-4.0.2 rabbimq-3.6.6 error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

```
    celery workers stops working.
    How to catch this error?
    Connection timeout can happen due to any other reason also.
```

```
    amqp==2.1.4
    billiard==3.5.0.2
    celery==4.0.2
    docopt==0.4.0
    kombu==4.0.2
    pkg-resources==0.0.0
    simplejson==3.10.0
    vine==1.1.3
```

```
    [2017-06-27 05:56:28,862: ERROR/MainProcess] Control command error: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
        Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages  /celery/worker/pidbox.py", line 42, in on_message
                self.node.handle_message(body, message)
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 129, in handle_message
                return self.dispatch(**body)
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 112, in dispatch
                ticket=ticket)
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 135, in reply
                serializer=self.mailbox.serializer)
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 265, in _publish_reply
                **opts
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
                exchange_name, declare,
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 203, in _publish
                mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1748, in _basic_publish
                (0, exchange, routing_key, mandatory, immediate), msg
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 64, in send_method
                conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 174, in write_frame
                write(view[:offset])
            File "/home/usher/virt/delivery/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 263, in write
                self._write(s)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
                return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
            error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: did you solve it? having same problem :-(